# Documentation for SpamAssassin rules (HTML_30_40)

Tags: spamassassin

I'd like to refine the password reset mails which are sent by my web application to avoid them to be mistaken as spam; a customer forwarded a mail header to me which contains several SpamAssassin rule names.

Some of the rules I could find, e.g. [BAYES_40](https://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/Rules/BAYES_40), but others I couldn't find there; those are:

- `HTML_30_40`
- `TO_NO_BRKTS_HTML_ONLY`
- `TO_NO_BRKTS_NORDNS`
- `TO_NO_BRKTS_NORDNS_HTML`

What do these rules mean; are there documentation pages somewhere?
The SpamAssassin which reported them is version 3.3.2; the latest version as of now is 3.4.1. Do those rules still exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `HTML_30_40` rule is no longer included in SpamAssassin, but if I remember correctly it was some test that concluded the email consisted of 30-40% HTML codes. Why that has any relevance for spam filtering I cannot see, and probably that is why it is no longer present.. :)

Those other rules still exist in SpamAssassin version 3.4.1. There is no explicit documentation per rule, other than an occasional comment or description along the rule implementation itself:

```
describe   TO_NO_BRKTS_HTML_ONLY       To: misformatted and HTML only
describe   TO_NO_BRKTS_NORDNS_HTML     To: misformatted and no rDNS and HTML only
```

You are probably sending emails from an ip-address with no reverse-DNS name, and the To: line is poorly formatted. Things should improve significantly if you get the DNS problems fixed (or relay the emails via your ISP) and format the To: line in the email properly, e.g.

```
To:  "J Random User" <jrnd@email>
```

Comment: Indeed it looks like the `"` quotes are not present ... I'll look into this, thank you! Furthermore I have changed the mails to `text/plain` format; and I'll look into the rDNS thing.